# How to extract url from youtube using https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={VideoId}

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={VideoId} to get the video id.

Previously there was a key url_encoded_fmt_stream_map that was used to get the URL. Now, it says url_encoded_fmt_stream_map key is not found.

There are only a few parameters for the video and it does not have an entry for url_encoded_fmt_stream_map

```
var videoInfoUrl = $"https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={VideoId}";

var videoPageContent = client.GetStringAsync(videoInfoUrl).Result;              

var videoParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(videoPageContent);           

var encodedStreamsDelimited = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(videoParameters["url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"]);
```

Error Information :

{System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map' was not present in the dictionary.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) [0x0001e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs:218

Comment: https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/issues/2615#issuecomment-530429387

Comment: @pree, from Jason's article, we can see it seems that YouTube has removed adaptive_fmts and url_encoded_fmt_stream_map from the player response,  YouTube has moved both of these into playerResponse as streamingData.adaptiveFormats and streamingData.formats, respecitively. You can take a look this article to get more info;https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/486